# Why mongoDB Node driver is creating unwanted connections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having a kind of strange problem when I trying to establish a single mongodb connection to a db with the mongodb nodejs native driver in the version 3.6.0.

My idea is to have just one connection opened through all the client session and reuse it in the different routes I have in my express server, when I hit it the first time the getDatabase function it creates two connections and after that one of it closes and one stands idle, but when I use a route, the second get opened again (it is like one connection just stays there and do nothing).

I just want to have one connection opened in my pool.

If you see the commented code i was testing with those options but none of them worked for me.

Pd: when I set the ***socketTimeoutMS*** to 5000ms just one connection is created but it auto-closes and reopen each 5000ms, which is weird (it reopen itself even when I don't use the connection).

All of this problem happen when I set the ***useUnifiedTopology*** to true (I can't set it to false because is deprecated and the other topologies will be removed in the next version of mdb ndjs driver)

[Here is an image with the strange behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5DEJ.png)

The code is:

```
import { MongoClient, Db } from 'mongodb';
import { DB_URI } from '../config/config';

// This mod works as DataBase Singleton

let db: Db;

export const getDataBase = async (id: string) => {
  try {
    if (db) {
      console.log('ALREADY CREATED');
      return db;
    } else {
      console.log('CREATING');
      let client: MongoClient = await MongoClient.connect(`${DB_URI}DB_${id}`, {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
   /*  minPoolSize: 1,
        maxPoolSize: 1,
        socketTimeoutMS: 180000,
        keepAlive: true,
        maxIdleTimeMS:10000
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        keepAlive: true,
        w: 'majority',
        wtimeout: 5000,
        serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
        connectTimeoutMS: 8000,
        appname: 'myApp',
        */
      });

      db = client.db();
      return db;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('DB Connection error', error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver internally creates one connection per known server for monitoring purposes. This connection is not used for application operations.

Hence, it is expected that you would get two connections established.

Comment: Thanks, I discovered it yesterday, this is the answer.